# How can I remove elements from a list of character vectors?

Tags: r, purrr, tidyverse

I have list that looks something like this:

```
what_i_have <- list(A = LETTERS[1:6], B = LETTERS[1:6], C = LETTERS[2:7])
```

I want to remove elements from each vector according to the name of that list element, so I end up with this:

```
what_i_want <- list(A = LETTERS[2:6], B = LETTERS[c(1, 3:6)], C = LETTERS[c(2,4:7)])
```

What manipulations can I do to `i_have_this` to get to `i_want_this`?

I have got as far as getting a list of logical vectors in the same structure by using `purrr::map2(what_i_have, names(what_i_have), function(x, y) x == y)`, but my brain is overloaded trying to subset `what_i_have`.

What am I missing? Can you help?

Bonus points for tidyverse (or base R) solutions.

```
library(testthat)
test_that("Turn what I have into what I want", {
  expect_equal(what_i_have, what_i_want)
})
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `x[x != y]`, this will remove elements that are equal to the names from `x`:

```
what_i_get <- purrr::map2(what_i_have, names(what_i_have), function(x, y) x[x != y])
identical(what_i_get, what_i_want)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

In base R, you can use `Map`:

```
Map(function(x, y) x[x != y], what_i_have, names(what_i_have))
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was a silly question, but my brain was overloaded!

Comment: or `map2(what_i_have, names(what_i_have), ~.x[.x != .y])`

Answer (score 2):

Simply,

```
Map(setdiff, have, names(have))
```